# Java remove properties in the ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, response, mybatis

I am using Java with Spring MVC and MyBatis to connect with the database. I have an account table and for some querys I need all the fields but for others I need to remove some properties.

For example to show basic information after the MyBatis query I have some fields null and others false or even 0, because the query doesn't need them. Initially I had this in my ResponseBody:

```
{
  "accountName": "Pagosonline.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "PayU - Latam",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "location": null,
  "secureName": null,
  "description": null,
  "document": "8301097231",
  "localOperation": false,
  "address": null,
  "acceptInternationalTransactions": false,
  "balance": 0
}
```

So, I used this annotation:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Account implements Serializable {...}
```

And now I have this ResponseBody without the null values:

```
{
  "accountName": "Pagosonline.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "PayU - Latam",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "document": "8301097231",
  "localOperation": false,      
  "acceptInternationalTransactions": false,
  "balance": 0
}
```

But as I don't use in the query the last 3 fields, them are returned false and 0. An alternative I've been thinking is to create another Entity Model just with the fields needed. But first I want to know if is any other solution, maybe removing those fields from the ResponseBody.

The expected response:

```
{
  "accountName": "Pagosonline.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "PayU - Latam",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "document": "8301097231"
}
```

Comment: Can you try this `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);` and have you tried the annotation in the field instead of class level? Also try `Include.NON_EMPTY` instead of `Include.NON_NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding [@JsonIgnoreProperties](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation to your Account class?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "balance", "acceptInternationalTransactions", "localOperation" })
```

As the docs say:

> Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of
>   properties (during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON
>   properties read (during deserialization).

Comment: Yeah, but it will ignore those properties for all methods that are using this Model. I just need to ignore them in some specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonFilter` and create your own `PropertyFilter`, based on your own criteria. It is really well documented [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria).

Comment: that's the answer